# Method SaveChanges() showing 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have encountered the error `'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException'`
at the point of `SaveChanges()` in my `POST` method.I have given the json through fiddler and it is showing error

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Unable to update the EntitySet
>   'Product_Category' because it has a DefiningQuery and no
>    element exists in the 
>   element to support the current operation.

I have tested the code through fiddler.
The Code is here

```
public void POST([FromBody] Product_Category pc)
{
    ProductionEntities2 pd = new ProductionEntities2();
    pd.Product_Category.Add(pc);
    pd.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Has your `ProductionEntities2` table a primary key?

Comment: No, actually it does not have primary key but Identity is there.

Comment: Try to declare a PK and try again.

Comment: Means in SQL table I have to change the table column??

Comment: Are you using a DB-First approach or Code-First one?

Comment: DB-First approach

Comment: OK. Check my answer to know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SaveChanges` this error usually occurs when you don't specify a [*Primary Key*](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) in your table. You need to specify a column as PK in your table and then **update your Entities** and try again.

If you are using DB-First approach:

[To create a primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys):

> 1. In Object Explorer, right-click the table to which you want to add a
>      unique constraint, and click Design.
> 2. In Table Designer, click the row selector for the database column
>      you want to define as the primary key. If you want to select
>      multiple columns, hold down the CTRL key while you click the row
>      selectors for the other columns.
> 3. Right-click the row selector for the column and select Set Primary
>      Key.

And if you are using Code-First approach use `[Key]` attribute. Just don't forget to add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` to your `using` directives first:

```
public class Product_Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But If I don't want primary key??

Comment: @Swadesh But why. As far as I know it is a good practice to have a PK in your tables always.

Comment: No because I want some field should be blank.

Comment: @Swadesh You can declare a column as PK and Identity and make other fields nullable.